# How do I pass an object in a WebAPI PUT?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, put

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and it's my first time working with an API.

I'm trying to do a PUT, given an object. However, after starting the application and looking at the available API, it shows my PUT URL as the following, without any option for arguments.

```
/api/File
```

Shouldn't it be something like `/api/File/{}`?

**Controller**

```
[HttpPut]
public void PutFile (FileData file)
{
  ...
}
```

If I'm doing this completely wrong, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

That URL is correct since the object you are sending should be passed in the body of the request with the correct content type.... probably multipart/form-data if you are uploading a file. If `FileData` is not a file and just a complex object then you could use application/x-www-form-urlencoded for forms or application/json for AJAX.

Comment: I see. `FileData` is a simple class that has a few variables in it that hold data. So when I want to call a PUT, I need to make a Request Object and fill it with data first?

Comment: It depends on how you want to make the request (e.g. form, ajax, WebClient, etc.) but generally, yes, populate your object and submit it to your controller.

Answer (score 0):

tforester answer is correct, but just to add. You need to use the [FromBodyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Web.Http.FromBodyAttribute%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) to tell webapi that the non primitive object (e.g. FileData) is expected and it's in the body of the incoming request. e.g.

```
[HttpPut]
public void PutFile ([FromBody]FileData file)
{
  ...
}
```